# IP Address ending in 'e.a.c' - What does it mean?

Tags: ip

I've registered the IP addresses of everyone who visited a certain page on my website. Most seem legit, but one looks like this:

`X.XXXXXX.e.a.c`

Where each `X` signifies one number (I've censored the address of course).

I've never encountered an IP address ending on `e.a.c`. A WHOIS lookup results in an error too. What does this address mean?

Comment: And does the beginning really looks like X.XXXXXX ??

Comment: @MedAl As I've stated in my post, each X signifies one number. But yes, that is the pattern: 1 number, followed by a dot, followed by six numbers.

Comment: Just wanted to ensure there was no typo. So, this is very strange